# Two people using Sharepoint - changes not saving (inconsistently)

Tags: content, save

I appreciate this question was asked and answered back in 2012, but this is 2019 and I'd like to know if there is a different problem. I spent 6 hours working on a document in SharePoint in the browser window. It looked like everything saved fine (remember, there is no 'save' button when working in a browser) but 1 week later, and a few additional entries later, some additions/changes stuck, but the lions share from a week ago have disappeared. My coworker was having trouble getting her work to save while working on the desktop version and saving.

I work for a governmental agency so am not able to do a lot except clear my cache. I don't want to spend another 6 hours re-entering the work only to have it disappear again. I'm on a deadline. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: check your version history and look for time stamps close to when you made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If one person is editing in the client app while one person is editing in the browser, the browser editor stops editing first, then the client editor saves their edits to SharePoint, the version that was edited in the client will over write the person that edited in the browser.  The only way to find the edits made in the browser is to then look at the version history of the document.  For this reason I typically recommend that everyone needs to edit in the browser, or everyone needs to edit in the client with check in / check out required.